# Validate cell that contains number and text excel

Tags: excel

I have vouchers from H-V-1000 to H-V-2000, how do I put validation that my partner can only input with that format and numbers are between 1000 and 2000.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried anything that you want to include in your question?

Comment: thanks for the reply but I'm stuck here :(

Comment: VBA has a `Split()` function.

Comment: I'm new to this, could you please help me

Comment: Just look at [data validation to cells](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) and apply a formula to test the input. `AND()` is a good start. Think about how you'd test a cell's input against different criteria inside that specific function. Give it an honest attempt. Tip: It's a simple formula in the end using `LEFT()` and `MID()` =)

Comment: I've tried that for half a day but zero results, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Dominique pls give me an example so I could learn from it

Comment: If you actually include your attempt I won't mind adding an answer. VBA is a patchwork-solution to something this simple. I'd avoid that.

Comment: @Dominique I've tried to search on google things similar to my question but can't find an answer. So I created this topic. I don't know about VBA so I'm asking for an easier way to use with "validation". Thank you

Comment: @JvdV pls help me with this

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.